# Округлить разницу в годах в меньшую сторону

Tags: дата, ms-access

Вычисляю разницу в годах:

```
SELECT DateDiff("yyyy",birthdate,now()) AS years
```

Разница округляется в большую сторону. 
Как округлить в меньшую сторону?
Т.е нужно получить сколько полных лет прошло

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
Public Function Age(datFrom As Date, datTo As Date) As Long
    Age = DateDiff("yyyy", datFrom, datTo)
    If DateAdd("yyyy", Age, datFrom) > datTo Then Age = Age - 1
End Function
```

И вызывать

```
SELECT Age(birthdate,now()) AS years
```